# Server-to-server websockets for a long running background service

Tags: rest, websocket, zeromq

I'm working on a tool that involves clients/users installing a middleware layer in their application web server stack. This middleware (think Rack for Ruby, or Express for Node) would need to communicate back to my central server for status updates.

Now, I can have it just do a GET every now and then in order to get the latest status, but it occurs to me that it might be cool to use a websocket in order to open a persistent connection. That way, it doesn't have to do any periodic polling, instead just keeping alive a websocket. When a status change occurs, I send an update down the websocket and the client receives it instantly.

Assuming I've got a stack that can handle tons of idle websocket connections, is this a horrible use of websockets? I know it's traditionally used for server-browser communication, but it seems like it could also be useful for behind the scenes server-server calls as well.

Would this be better implemented as a more generic TCP socket communication instead of a websocket, something like ZeroMQ? I guess I don't have much experience at the socket layer, and REST/websockets are a lot more familiar to me.